# The method of goBack() does not work in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview

**In my activity which contains a WebView, I override onBackPressed() method, here is my code.**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(mWebView.canGoBack()){
        Log.d("DEBUG","canGoBack");
        mWebView.goBack();
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**String "canGoBack" is printed if there is a history page, but the activity has no change. Here is my initialize WebView code which is invoked in onCreate() method.**

```
private void initWebViewSettings() {
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE); //no cache
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
}
```

**Here is my onResume() method, I invoke loadUrl().**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mShopId = getIntent().getIntExtra(App.SHOP_ID,-1);
    if(mShopId != -1){
        mWebView.loadUrl(App.SHOP_URL + mShopId + App.INDEX);
    }
}
```

Comment: Has it been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is my solution for this issue. I did the same way for many webview project

```
webView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            WebView webView = (WebView) v;

            switch(keyCode)
            {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if(webView.canGoBack())
                    {
                        webView.goBack();
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I don not think that. The log suggest goBack() method is invoked. But my activity has no change. If there is two history pages, press twice back, it just go back  to my last activity. I think it need to be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Try out my solution for getting back to the old link on pressing key down

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_BACK && webView.canGoBack()){

        webView.goBack();
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

Comment: just try calling this method for a time and check if it is working or not.like webview.onKeyDown(code,Ke)